# OGNL is extremely slow when in debug mode (Tomcat 7)

Tags: eclipse, performance, debugging, tomcat, ognl

We have project which utilizes OGNL (3.0.6). When Tomcat server is started in RUN mode, OGNL expression execution takes <1ms. However, when server is in DEBUG mode, same expression executes in around 80 ms, that is 80+ times slower! I have tried everything I could imagine off - disabling OGNL logging (*log4j.logger.ognl=FATAL*), tweaking DEBUG settings in Eclipse (latest STS 3.3.0) - nothing helps even a bit. What is interesting, this slowdown occured after I have re-installed STS and created brand new workspace. In older STS (same 3.3.0 version) everything was OK, however debugger integration was completely broken (that was the case for re-install). I must mention also, that I'm not alone - my colleague has the same problem with his Eclipse setup.
Please, maybe someone have had similar problems. I would be **enormously** grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Eclipse. Oddly, all I did to fix the problem was clear all breakpoints. 
This guy helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373547