# Long time of deploy only before debug

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, netbeans-7, apache-tomee

I have one project in Java EE, I use Apache TomEE 1.5.2 Server and NetBeans IDE 7.3.1

When I open project with my app and I choose "Run" option or "Deploy" (undeploy current file from server and deploy) option it last a few second (eg. `(total time: 5 seconds)`). But when I choose "Debug" option (undeploy current file from server, deploy and run app in debug mode) it last much more: 6 minute.

How can you explain it?

**Note**

For NetBeans 8 Beta I get time 9 minute and for NetBeans 7.4 I get 7-8 minute, more then for 7.3 :(

Comment: can you try it in netbeans 7.4 or even better netbeans 8.0 beta(has more native support for tomee).

Comment: @Ravshan in NetBeans 7.4 and 8 i get same strange situation

Comment: I had a similar problem when my netbeans was configured to use a proxy server, maybe you check it up?

Comment: @Ravshan I change in option to don't use proxy server, but it didn't help. I get same times on Netbeans 7.3.1, 7.4 and 8 Beta

Comment: i can recommend you some more steps to check: 1. Fresh unzip tomee. 2. try to deploy fresh new application(maybe problem is related with your application)

Comment: @Ravshan for new application deployed at new server i get same effect. For new application "Hello world",  deploy on TomEE last 2 minute

Comment: Have you tried older versions of netbeans (7.0, 7.1,...)? Unrelated from that: Is there anything suspicious in the NB log files?

Comment: In Netbeans 7.1 it's ok (last 44 sec). I don't find anything suspicious in the NB log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable all breakpoints, some breakpoints such as conditional breakpoints on very frequently used classes or method breakpoints in general can cause a great slowdown in debug mode.

Also increase the PermGen settings, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369487/speeding-up-tomcat-in-debug-mode-with-eclipse-ide) as well. By disabling all breakpoints, you should get a startup time comparable to the non debug run.

Then try to enable the breakpoints back one by one to see which one is causing the problem.