# Intelliji idea is very slow in debug mode and it is running perfectly in normal mode

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea

Intelliji idea is very slow in debug mode and it is running perfectly in normal mode.

I already tried by setting the below thing in /etc/hosts file
sudo nano /etc/hosts and add these two entries.

127.0.0.1 .local
::1 .local

But it did not work out for me.

Any help on this is highly regarded.

Comment: Are you setting any breakpoints on method signatures themselves instead of method bodies? That dramatically slows things down.

Comment: Also tell intellij to clear all your existing breakpoints in case they exist in long forgotten code.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544799.

Comment: I tried all the options which you mentioned but still it is very slow.

Comment: Issue still exists with 2022.1.3 version

Answer (score 41):

Remove breakpoints off your method and use them inside the method as that can cause your debug to take a very long time.

Try running IntelliJ as admin. I had this issue at work where debugging was extremely slow and running as admin actually made it a lot faster.

[Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062069/method-breakpoints-may-dramatically-slow-down-debugging)

There is a simple explanation from the IntelliJ Team: "Method breakpoints will slow down debugger a lot because of the JVM design, they are expensive to evaluate"

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping

Comment: I cleared all the breakpoints and set a break point for a line which is inside the method but still it is very slow.I am running intellij as admin

Comment: Maybe reinstall jdk and IntelliJ?

Comment: if i ran normal java application ,it is working fine.If I run appium testcases with intelliji then the debugger is slow

Comment: Can you please confirm if you have any breakpoints set? open up the breakpoint window in IntelliJ and make sure there is nothing set. let me know the outcome and I'll try to assist further.  `Run --> View Breakpoints`. If you find any, remove them all then try run debug again (is it still slow?)

Comment: I removed all the breakpoints and tried to run it .But it is still slow in debug mode with appium but it is running fine for normal java application.

Comment: Can you try to isolate the issue to determine what exactly is slow? is it certain parts of the code? is it initializing the tests? is it certain calls that are giving you performance problems?

Comment: Automate any mobile app test either android or iOS using appium with java and try to debug the code.Then it is taking 1 or 3  minutes to  step over to the next step and fetch the variable values.Hover the mouse on any variable is also not working.

Comment: In my case it was an accidentally set Java Field Watchpoint (breakpoint for an instance variable), removing it solved the slowness issue in debug mode.

Answer (score 29):

If you **disable** this options in ***Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views --> Java***, things will start work faster when debugging.

[image]

Comment: My issue was the `toString()`. My suspicion is that it got confused by lazily loaded database entity attributes. I wish there was an extra option there to "Disable 'toString()' object view For classes from the list". I would add all my entities there to be sure that's the issue

Comment: This worked for me, question is, how does this affect the speed and does it have any other efffects?

Comment: I don't know when IntelliJ started having the values inline during debbug. In my case that was a big issue as I had a big object graph in memory and IntelliJ is calling toString() on everything to have values inline. On the same Preferences menu above "Data Views" you have now the option to disable that feature

Answer (score 23):

I had the similar issue. In my case it was **method breakpoints**. There was just one break point on a method. My spring boot app took around 20 mins to launch. When I removed the breakpoints it took 4 seconds to launch.

I also changed the debugger settings.

1. Unchecked - Enable alternative view view for Collections classes
2. Unchecked - Enable 'toString()' object view:

but these settings didn't make a difference.

Comment: I also faced similar issue... but i had breakpoint at field level. the sprint boot application took 10 times more than normal boot time..

Answer (score 8):

clicked on "Mute Breakpoints" and started it and it started like as if starting in normal mode(means no any delay)

[image]

Comment: This helped me, is an immediate confirmation whether breakpoints were the issue also.  Try muting it during initialization, then turning it back on before your test executes.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved a similar problem by disabling breakpoints; it was remote debugging.
I did not make any performance measurements, but it looks like it is ok to have about 10 active breakpoints, but disastrous to have about 100 of them (I guess, the breakpoint list is sent over the network).

Idea lets you to group breakpoints and disable the whole groups.

Note that a click on the wrong mouse button clears your breakpoint instead of letting you edit its condition, so be careful!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just had to disable the option: "Show method returns values"
[Image of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzJPb.png)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem, after deleting all breakpoints it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Removing all Interface method breakpoints will fix the long spring boot startup Idea debug run.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't use "biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender" among your logs. In my case usage of such kind of appender was the cause of drastically slow starting in debug mode.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, doesn't matter if its run or debug. Always when the gelf appender is enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you use a GELF (Graylog Extended Log Format) appender for local dev/debugging? It sends all your logs to you graylog server (which can be slow of course, especially if you don't use the UDP version)

Answer (score 1):

Remove breakpoint from DAO interface and all work nice!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue and the issue was having a breakpoint in one of the method signatures in the repository methods. After removing that, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with the Eclipse also and found the solution.
It is happening because your IntelliJ is using online Java and not using the same which is installed in your system.

You should set the java path to your system one in the IntelliJ configuration. Below link will help you for the same:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Hope this will help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, slowness is specific to REST calls. After testing all of the above proposed solutions, I finally find a way to remove these slowness issues by switching my JDK from JDK 11 to JDK 8.

Note: The same slowness appears in Visual Studio Code. This seems related to JDK 11 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode) on macOS)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had more than 100 breakpoints active and this was the cause of this issue.
I clicked `Ctrl + Alt + F8` and disabled all the breakpoints.
After that i enabled few new breakpoints i needed and all was ok.
It seems that having a lot of active breakpoints causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by the "Threads" view. When I remove this view it becomes fast again.

When I add the Threads view, I continuously see "Collecting data..." in the threads view, it flickers every 5s where the threads list shows for a moment then it goes back to "Collecting data...". When its like this, stepping through the code is painfully slow - takes about 10s for each step.

Answer (score 0):

I cam across this post looking for a solution for my CLion (Rust). I removed all breakpoints, and it was enough to make the starting time on the debug mode too quick again.

Thanks to everyone who suggested that. This suggestion does not work only for Java, it also works for Rust/Clion