# IntelliJ IDEA stucks at "collecting data" while debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to debug remote tomcat application.

It works perfect before.

However, for recent times, it always get stuck at "collecting data", though the data is very small.

I have searched on this site, and tried:

[Intelliji idea is very slow in debug mode and it is running perfectly in normal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292095/intelliji-idea-is-very-slow-in-debug-mode-and-it-is-running-perfectly-in-normal)

[IntelliJ freezes for about 30 seconds before debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625785/intellij-freezes-for-about-30-seconds-before-debugging)

Still does not work

Comment: What's the Suspend Policy? Does switching it to [Thread](https://i.imgur.com/c5vbeA2.png) help? See [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544799). If it doesn't help, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach the following: [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085), [thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899) of IntelliJ IDEA and Tomcat processes using `jstack`, `.idea` directory contents from the project. Specify IntelliJ IDEA, Java and Tomcat versions you are using.

Comment: [Debugger logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241125) may be also helpful.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  It's thread policy.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Not yet. I will file a bug and attach the log files.

Comment: @CrazyCoder After closing the threads view, it became faster.

Comment: I had the same and here was my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447369/3554624

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find this happens only when I open both *Thread View* and *Variable View*, like this

[image]

So I closed the *Thread View*, and it became much faster:

[image]

Comment: I cant believe this actually solves my debugging issue.

Comment: I was hoping for it but it's not enough

Comment: On intellij IDEA 2022.1 this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 the issue touched only `List`-like collections (thus all objects containing them as fields).
What helped me is disabling `Enabling alternative view for Collection classes` option in Settings > Debugger > Data Views > Java:
[image]
Now it shows collection size and expandable items instead of `Collecting data...`:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for if the variable `x` is stuck at "Collecting data...", evaluating its methods like `x.toString()` still worked for me to view its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `"Enable 'toString()' object view"` in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views > Java solved the problem for me.

I'm running on 2023.1(UE)