# Debugger inspect stuck on Evaluating in Android Studio Hedgehog

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, watch

I am working on an Android app with Android Studio and almost whenever I try to inspect variables the debugger gets stuck on "Evaluating".

I was suspecting that this was occurring when trying to debug a background task (which is nonsense too), but the fact is now I'm trying to debug and inspect variables in the main thread, so now it is me who is stuck.

I tried some solutions found on Stack Overflow to no avail, like this:

[IntelliJ IDEA stuck at "collecting data" while debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75404006/2807741)

I've just disabled "Enabled alternative views for Collections classes" in settings, as the post suggest, but nothing happened.

How can I get back to being able to debug and inspect variables correctly?

[image: Debugging]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue after upgrading to hedgehog.
Somehow the buildconfiguration got set up wrong.
I had to change *com.mypackage.* to *com.mypackage.myapp*
Then Cleaning the project as well as invalidating all caches fixed it for me.
However instantiating the tests now takes a lot more time than in the previous version.

Comment: Hello @nepho5, and thanks for your reply. In my case I was checking the BuildConfig files and the packages are fine, so I don't think this is the problem.