# Android debugger stuck at collecting data

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debug

In my Android project, when I attempt to debug project in emulator then want to see the data within the variables, it gets stuck at collecting data

[image: These are variables which i want to see data]

[image: Normally, I should be able to see the data when I hover over it, but it gets stuck like this.]

I upgrade android studio giraffe to hedgehog, Invalidated cache and restart option none of these works

idea.log entries

```
2024-02-01 15:51:05,391 [2732310]   INFO - waitForClientReadyForDebug - Waiting for clients [tr.com.X.X] for 15 seconds
2024-02-01 15:51:05,483 [2732402]   INFO - #com.android.ddmlib - Device 'Pixel_2 [emulator-5554]' tracking jdwp process (pid=13790)
2024-02-01 15:51:05,960 [2732879]   INFO - #com.android.ddmlib - Device 'Pixel_2 [emulator-5554]' jdwp process '13790' is now known as pkg='tr.com.X.X' (proc='tr.com.X.X')
2024-02-01 15:51:05,965 [2732884]   INFO - #com.android.ddmlib - Device 'Pixel_2 [emulator-5554]' jdwp process '13790' is now known as pkg='tr.com.X.X' (proc='tr.com.X.X')
2024-02-01 15:51:05,966 [2732885]   INFO - #com.android.ddmlib - Device 'Pixel_2 [emulator-5554]' jdwp process '13790' is now known as pkg='tr.com.X.X' (proc='tr.com.X.X')
2024-02-01 15:51:05,975 [2732894]   INFO - waitForClientReadyForDebug - Found process tr.com.X.X. Waiting for it to be debuggable.
2024-02-01 15:51:05,975 [2732894]   INFO - waitForClientReadyForDebug - tr.com.X.X is now debuggable.
2024-02-01 15:51:05,977 [2732896]   INFO - #com.android.ddmlib - Device 'Pixel_2 [emulator-5554]' jdwp process '13790' is now known as pkg='tr.com.X.X' (proc='tr.com.X.X')
2024-02-01 15:51:06,060 [2732979]   INFO - #c.i.o.w.i.ToolWindowManagerImpl - Ignore setShowStripeButton(id=Android Profiler, value=true) - not applicable for a new UI
2024-02-01 15:51:06,096 [2733015]   INFO - #c.i.o.w.i.ToolWindowManagerImpl - Ignore setShowStripeButton(id=App Inspection, value=true) - not applicable for a new UI
2024-02-01 15:51:06,111 [2733030]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-02-01 15:51:06,189 [2733108]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
2024-02-01 15:51:13,918 [2740837]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-02-01 15:51:20,965 [2747884]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
```

Comment: Sometimes one can get more info by looking at IDE logs - use the menu 'Help | Show Log in Explorer' and open 'idea.log' in text editor and look at bottom or "tail" it when debugging.  This is usually a last resort since this will all be internal info but if you were to report the issue this log is used among other things.

Comment: I shared the log entries. I thing there is no entry regarding the problem.

Comment: There is a similar problem description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672613/debugger-inspect-stuck-on-evaluating-in-android-studio-hedgehog) ; however the solution does not seem promising.  Also [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=studio%20debugger%20stuck%20evaluating) is the bugtrack db with a search on some keywords - quite few reports but didn't see any solution after a very brief review.  (May have to login - not sure).  For grins I'd probably try a different "fresh" emulator.