Android Studio debugger not working always show Collecting data
My Android Studio debugger isn't working. When it hits a breakpoint, it shows "collecting data" all the time (Emulator and Device), making it difficult for me to work efficiently.
Previously, I was using the Canary version, where the debugger still worked. Then I tried updating to the Flamingo version, but the debugger stopped working.
So I switched back to the Canary version, but found that the debugger didn't work there either. I decided to completely uninstall Android Studio and install the latest version, Koala, but it still didn't work. I'm very frustrated and have tried to fix it, but now I'm out of options.
Here, my information
Screenshot  and MAC info
private fun playSound() {
  Timber.d("playSound()")
  if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
    mediaPlayer.stop()
  }
  mediaPlayer.reset()
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.error_sound_2)
  mediaPlayer.start()
}

Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.6.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true

I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it. Thank you for any solutions!
I also referred to the following questions:

disabled the Android NDK Support plugin in Android Studio.
Program freeze, Can't go to view as and select object instead of Kotlin class


question regarding the breakpoint-position. I am facing the same issue, if the breakpoint is in followup call of app-startup (e.g. onCreate). Is it same at yours? If so, try a breakpoint anywhere else (e.g. onClick which is based on userinput) and share your outcome please.

@Marcel Sadly, I encounter this issue at every breakpoint-position. If you find any solution, please let me know.

Sorry, but unfortunately I don't have any for your issue, yet.
But I had another issue with the debugger where this helped; try a different set of ticks in the boxes at:
Settings->Build, Execution,Deployment->Debugger->Data Views->Java
especially give a try to activate "Enable 'toString()' object view
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913491/intellij-idea-stucks-at-collecting-data-while-debug
my problems disappered with the Android Studio version 2023.1.1 from Nov'23

I had this issue until I disabled "Enable 'toString()' object view" on Android settings.


Thank you very much. I tried adjusting as you suggested at the first breakpoint. Now I can see the values in the variables. However, at the next breakpoint, my debugger freezes. Are you experiencing the same issue, or does it work fine for you? Additionally, what specs are you using for your MacBook?
Mine is 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7.
